# Generating authorization headers automatically

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Right now I generate authentication headers using a website - OAuth tool. Then I create the following code:

```
$opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'method'=>"GET",
                'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                    "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" . 
                    'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="343432dsddsf", ' .
                    'oauth_nonce="3432fsdfsdf", ' .
                    'oauth_signature="423fsdfsdfsdf%3D", ' .
                    'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", ' .
                    'oauth_timestamp="1431435892", ' .
                    'oauth_version="1.0"'
            )
        );
        //191683771
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $source = @file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=200&user_id=112344123', false, $context);
```

To get the JSON data.

It works, but I want the user_id parameter to be changed. I have the whole array of users for which I want to retrieve this data.

But then, I can't do that as I would have to generate authentication headers for all users myself.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Anyone knows the answer?